# StorSimple Array - failover error

Tags: azure, storage

I've deactivated a device with some files on it (cca 11 GB). The instructions say, that device should be deactivated, and failover side should have same or higher capacity, active and joined in same domain. 
I've done all prerequisites, even on an new virtual machine (1200 series are been run on Hyper-V machines).
Any ideas?

[Screenshot with concrete error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8PY2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

*solved*

Just create a new VHDx with some GB more (if first share was 500 GB, add new VHDx with 600 gb space - differential).